# How can i know when calling a java method from Kotlin if a nullable argument should be checked at call site?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, call, nullable

As a junior programmer who needs to pass from java to Kotlin, I'm asking a lot of questions about the Integration between Kotlin and Java.
I have read the following link:
[Calling Java From Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)

but it seems that I still have difficulty when calling a java method.
For example if I have a *TextView* in my Kotlin code:

```
 val secondaryTextColor : Int? = weakReferenceContext.get()?.resources?.getColor(R.color.secondary_text_color)
 secondaryTextColor?.let {
     holder.someTextView.setTextColor(it)
 }
```

The code above **won't be compiled** without the *let* block. If I tried to compile without the *let*, It will cause a compilation error saying the *setTextColor* expected an *Int* but get an *Int?*
I'm looking in the java source code, and there is any place that is written the *int*  parameter can't be null.
So the only way that I have to know that may be a problem is by the editor or by compiling and getting the **error**.
I'm asking if the is a way that from the java source code I will be able to know if the method will accept a nullable argument or not.
I hope the way I wrote the post is clear what I'm asking and if not please tell me and I will try to elaborate it, cause I **really** need to understand once and forever

Comment: any reason why you are declering `secondaryTextColor` as `Int?` and not just `Int` if you know that `getColor` can't return null?

Comment: First of all , how can I know that *getColor* can't return null?
Secondly, the all path can return null:weakReference.get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the return type of `weakReferenceContext.get()?.resources?.getColor(R.color.secondary_text_color)`?

It is an `Int?` (a nullable `Int`).

So `secondaryTextColor` has a type of `Int?`, if you want to use it as a parameter in a function that expects type `Int` (like your `someTextView.setTextColor`) you have to find a way around it.

Why does `TextView#setTextColor` require a non-null parameter? If you look at the docs you can see it has the following signature:

```
public void setTextColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

In the signature, `int` is a primitive type in Java. There is no opportunity for this to be null. Hence, Kotlin interprets this as:

```
fun setTextColor(@ColorInt color: Int)
```

There are different ways to get around nullability here. One way is using the `let` block. Please have a look [at the official docs on null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) to learn more

Addendum:
`@ColorInt` is an annotation. `Int`s representing colors can be references to resources `@ColorRes` or a color that represents a packed `ARGB`. See the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/ColorInt)

Comment: all my post I emphasize that I know how to use *let* and my example is with *let*. The question is **How can I know that setTextColor won't accept an Int?**

Comment: thanks. Small issues please :)  : 1. Does @ColorInt have an important meaning?  2. If a function in java gets not a primitive type, than can  I conclude that a nullable type can be send to it?

Comment: In the absence of nullability annotations for non-primitives, the assumption should always be that `null` is not allowed, unless the javadocs for that method say that null is acceptable. It is Java convention to assume non-nullables unless the docs say otherwise.

Comment: Kotlin will not enforce this convention, though. That's what the `!` type is that you can see in the IDE when hovering Java methods that have no nullability annotations. It means you can pass null (or assume non-null return value) at your own risk. e.g. you better check the java docs.

Comment: @DorVak can you please accept my answer (green tick)? And, yes, Java supports nullable and non-nullable annotations. Kotlin will use these to infer the type as non-null or null when you call Java from Kotlin

Comment: Thank you all :)